# How to safely upload and download PDF files stored in the file system using PHP

Tags: php, security, pdf, file-upload, filesystems

I've tried to look around for some tricks on how I can do this safely, without executing the code.
Does the code get executed if i simply upload it to the file system, then leave it be until someone downloads it?
Or is this a potential threat aswell?

What I am trying to do is making the users able to upload their CV in pdf files. The administrator can then download this pdf file (not being viewed on server, but downloaded).

How should I do this to prevent malicious files from being executed on my server? Also, would it be risky to place this folder OUTSIDE the public_html folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot of risk to upload .pdf in a folder.
the folder must be in 644 (chmod). and have a index.php with redirect to the index of the website 
Inside or outsite the "public_html" .. it's not a problem

when you upload, you can check the extension (.pdf) and type mime:

with finfo_file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php )
and 
with `$extension = substr($file, -3);`

Comment: Does it matter what the folder access is like if the files are just being uploaded and downloaded without any PHP script executing them? Or is it possible that they can execute by themselves?

Comment: If the file(s) don't have execute permitions and if nobody call it.. they can't execute itself ...

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how your server is set. If it allows PDF files to be used as executable, or to be opened with particular application/processing script that could be used for malicious actions. Otherwise you have to follow simple instructions such as restriction of file name length and avoiding to perform read operation of that file. As I understand you need only to upload and safe them. I'd keep them in public_html and once uploaded correctly (you checked filesize, extension etc) moved them whenever you like.